# Python MySql query silently failing

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a MySql database (running using the stock Docker image) and it contains a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Edits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `context` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`context`,`field`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm connecting to it in a WSGI application, and my connection code looks like this:

```
import contextlib
import MySQLdb

mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'host', db = 'db')

def _cursor():
  mysql.ping(True)
  return contextlib.closing(mysql.cursor())

def _exec(sql, params = None):
  with _cursor() as c:
    c.execute(sql, params)

def save_edits(id, context, field, value, username):
  return _exec('REPLACE INTO Edits SET id = %(id)s, context = %(context)s, 
    field = %(field)s, value = %(value)s, username = %(username)s, 
    requested = UTC_TIMESTAMP()', {
      'id': id,
      'context': context,
      'field': field,
      'value': value,
      'username': username,
  })
```

When I call the `save_edits` function, it doesn't throw an exception, but it fails to update the database. Furthermore, attempting to run the query `REPLACE INTO Edits SET id = 1, context = 'x', field = 'y', value = 'z', username = 'foo', requested = UTC_TIMESTAMP();` through a `mysql` shell afterwards fails with an `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` error. If I wait about 5 minutes, however, that error goes away and I can run the `REPLACE INTO` query against the MySql database again.

What's going on? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you need to explicitly commit the update?

Comment: The first thing I would try is running the query `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATE = 0;` sometimes the safe updates will catch stuff and won't let you update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `autocommit` is `false` by default, and closing the cursor without closing the connection will keep the transaction open. I changed the method to:

```
def _exec(sql, params = None):
  with _cursor() as c:
    c.execute(sql, params)
    mysql.commit()
```

And that fixed the problem.